# iptables allow everything, is it safe?

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, webserver, port

The os is Ubuntu Server 18 and I am running a web server on it.

Is it safe to accept all traffic on all ports?

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I tried restricting ports and only allow a few, but then my ftp server doesn't work even tho I specifically opened port 21...

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "safe". Iptables won't block anything in that situation, so if you rely on that for safety, it's not safe, but it won't *in it self* cause any problems, and as such it can be called safe.

Regarding making FTP work through firewalls: what happens on port 21 is only the control stuff, for any actual data transfer an additional connection is made. Which direction those connections are made in, depends on whether it's active or passive FTP, often you'll also have to configure your FTP server software. But you should also look into whether some modern alternative (SFTP or webdav to name two) is usable, the FTP protocol is old and it shows.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to hide yourself behind a firewall, which means the firewall should have some active restriction policies in place. When it's opened up it's as if it were not there at all. If you have just the web server and want to offer it to any network, then the result is the same. But if only you do something else without the firewall, it immediately becomes available from the outside. There are many factors involved like what the machine is. But the rule should be (in my opinion) to expose only what you intend to have exposed. All the rest should be covered.

Another aspect are the limits of exposure, which the firewall can set.

My advise is to learn at least the basics of iptables and always have them applied. There are also many helper applications like [this one](https://github.com/tomasz-warniello/Waterwall), which is a rework and adjustment of [this one](https://github.com/bmaeser/iptables-boilerplate), which you may prefer.